# How to get row occurrence value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following table

```
id   name   amount
1    aaa     1000
2    bbb     1500
3    ccc     1700
4    ddd     2000
5    aaa     1400
6    aaa     1700
7    bbb     1800
```

What I need is one more column to display the occurrence value based on the name as follows

```
 id   name   amount   occurrence
  1    aaa     1000     1
  2    bbb     1500     1
  3    ccc     1700     1
  4    ddd     2000     1
  5    aaa     1400     2
  6    aaa     1700     3
  7    bbb     1800     2
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've removed the PhpMyAdmin tag, assuming you want to write a SQL query rather than fetching this information by clicking on the program's user interface. Please edit the question again if I was wrong.

Comment: Should we assume that the list will always be sorted by `id`, or should we ensure that it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT id, name, amount, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM mytable AS t2
        WHERE t2.name = t1.name AND t2.id <= t1.id) AS occurrence
FROM mytable AS t1
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/MGHPIU48863)